# Convert nanoseconds (since midnight) to printable time using std::chrono?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

How would you convert a `uint64_t` (representing the number of nanoseconds since midnight) in to a human-readable time such as:

```
HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn
```

using the standard C++ Chrono library?

Comment: in general - you cannot convert time since midnight into dd-mm-yyyy, because it is not date, but duration, duration can be converted into weeks-days-hours...

Comment: I'd take a look at https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date which is heading towards being part of the standard

Comment: A `uint64_t` holding nanoseconds since midnight of what exact day? You're saying you want to print 'DD-MM-YYYY' besides the time-of-day and so you need to specify whether the nanoseconds are since midnight of some standard epoch or else say where from to get the date.

Comment: Guys, I have edited my question to reflect my mistake (apologies). If someone could "unhold" this?

Comment: Use [Howard Hinnant's datetime library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) like [this](http://wandbox.org/permlink/YrH17FG4sIwj1kF5).

Comment: @HowardHinnant When will your library be added to the std?

Comment: @mezamorphic:  My library is currently in the C++20 draft spec, which we hope will become official before 2021.

Answer (score 1):

**Clarification**
If you're only given the number of nanoseconds since the most recent midnight, it will be impossible to know what the date is (as Llya Bursov pointed out).

*ie. If I tell you its 4:30, you would have no way of knowing today is August 10th.*

So I'm going to assume you're trying to convert **epoch time** (number or seconds since Jan 1 1970 ) into a human readable date.

To get started, check out [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/) page as a guide.

**Answer 1**
[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) is the "official" way to convert epoch time into human readable time in C++

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << std::ctime(&result);
}
```

This is for getting the current epoch time and converting it into human readable date and time. This does assume seconds, instead of nano seconds. If you need nano seconds, simply divide the number of nano-seconds by 1E9. There are 1E9 nano-seconds in one second. You'll be left with the number of seconds, and then can convert it to human readable code.

If you also use [number of nano-seconds % 1E9 ] the result will be the number of nano-seconds, in case that's important. This number can be added onto the end of the date returned from the above code.

**Answer 2**
If instead, you don't need the date, and only need to convert nano-seconds to human readable time (HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn) Then see this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

long fibonacci(unsigned n)
{
    if (n < 2) return n;
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "f(42) = " << fibonacci(42) << '\n';
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);

    std::cout << "finished computation at " << std::ctime(&end_time)
              << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
}
```

See [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) for help with duration.

**Let me know if this solved your question, or if I answered the wrong question.**

Comment: Hi, apologies- yes you're correct, I wouldn't know the date! However, I HAVE been given the number of nanoseconds since the previous midnight. How would I print this in the form HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn?

Comment: The second example doesn't show how to make whatever type the system clock returns from a nanoseconds since midnight. Nor does it show how to make a duration from the difference. I'm not sure how this answers the question?